# Unit testing | Mocking FileOutputStream using Mockk.io

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, mockk

I need to test three things from the below mentioned method:

- verify `output.write(any<ByteArray>())` is called
- verify `output.close()` is called
- assert that `fullPath` is returned

```
fun saveFile(fullPath: String, model: SomeDataModel): String? {
        try {
            val output = FileOutputStream(fullPath)
            output.write(Base64.decode(model.someString, Base64.DEFAULT))
            output.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            return null
        }
        return fullPath
 }
```

Facing issue:

- Mocking `FileOutputStream`

Tried:

```
    @Test
    fun `saveFile returns file path if fileOutputStream write succeeds`() {
        val fullPath = "test/full/path"
        val model = SomeDataModel()
        val stringByteArray: ByteArray? = someModel.someString?.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset())


        mockkStatic("android.util.Base64")
        every { Base64.decode(model.someString, Base64.DEFAULT) } returns stringByteArray

        mockkConstructor(FileOutputStream::class)
        val fileOutputStream = mockk<FileOutputStream>()
        every { constructedWith<FileOutputStream>(OfTypeMatcher<String>(String::class)) } returns fileOutputStream
        // Getting error on above line: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock

        every { saveFile(fullPath, model) } returns filePath

        val result = saveFile(fullPath, model)

        verify { fileOutputStream.write(stringByteArray) }

        assertEquals(fullPath, result)
    }
```

Please help me to write correct test case using Mockk.io/Mockito

Comment: It would be very easy to wrap your function inside a class which has `FileOutputStream` and a wrapper for `Base64.decode` as injectable parameters (like constructor)

Comment: Hi @Neo, can you share sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

In line `every { constructedWith<FileOutputStream>(OfTypeMatcher<String>(String::class)) } returns fileOutputStream` you must not return the mock object `fileOutputStream`, but a non-mock object. Have a look at https://mockk.io/#constructor-mocks